# Image Picker on ipad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I know image picker on the iPad needs to be a popover, and I keep trying but it won't work and crashes when I tap the button that calls the popover.

```
   -(IBAction)addPhoto:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc]
             initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).frame
                             inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                           animated:YES];
}


    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    // Delete any existing image.
    NSManagedObject *oldImage = imageClass.image;
    if (oldImage != nil) {
        [imageClass.managedObjectContext deleteObject:oldImage];
    }

    // Create an image object for the new image.
    NSManagedObject *myImage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:imageClass.managedObjectContext];
    imageClass.image = myImage;

    // Set the image for the image managed object.
    [image setValue:selectedImage forKey:@"image"]; 
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: It crashes the second i tap the button that's supposed to show the popover

Comment: what's in the backtrace?

Comment: 2012-11-29 21:52:25.189 Interface[4808:c07] -[UIBarButtonItem frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x817e880
2012-11-29 21:52:25.190 Interface[4808:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x817e880'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x1fa3012 0x13e0e7e 0x202e4bd 0x1f92bbc 0x1fcf77e 0x5c26 0x13f4705 0x1f920 0x25bb24 0x13f4705 0x1f920 0x1f8b8 0xe0671 0xe0bcf 0xdfd38 0x4f33f 0x4f552 0x2d3aa 0x1ecf8 0x1efedf9 0x1efead0 0x1f18bf5 0x1f18962 0x1f49bb6 0x1f48f44 0x1f48e1b 0x1efd7e3 0x1efd668 0x1c65c 0x2b0d 0x2a35 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception you are getting, the problem is that the `sender` for the `addPhoto` method is actually a `UIBarButtonItem`, not a `UIButton`. You need to change how the popover is displayed from using the button's frame to being displayed from the bar button.

```
-(IBAction)addPhoto:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
         initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

    [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
        animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create property to store Your popover controller or store content controller. Seems that one of view controllers releases right after end of method. Also, iOS 7 have awful behavior of UIImagePickerController in popover.
[This is related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026329/ios-7-image-picker-inside-popover-wrong-behavior)